# Custom error from Django Rest Framework is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I trying to return a JSON response from Django exceptions, I have implemented the following function

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
if isinstance(exc, Http404):
    logging.exception('Uncaught Exception', exc_info=exc)
    return Response(str(exc), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

response = exception_handler(exc, context)


if response is None:
    logging.exception('Uncaught Exception', exc_info=exc)
    return Response({'detail': 'Server Error'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

if isinstance(exc, (DeisException, ServiceUnavailable, HealthcheckException)):
    logging.exception(exc.__cause__, exc_info=exc)

return response
```

And I have added these in my `settings.py` file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'views.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

But I am still getting a HTML file rather than a JSON resonse.

Comment: Can you share the code that is raising the exception? The exception handler only handles certain exceptions

Comment: This is the global exception from Django rest framework

Comment: What global exception? What is the error that is not being handled by your custom exception handler?

Comment: `custom_exception_handler` needs to accept a second argument `context`